# Solving an optimization problem in QCP form

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, quadratic-programming, qcqp

I am reading a paper in which authors said quadratic-constrained optimization is used for the following problem:

\begin{align}
&\underset{\mathbf{P},\,\,\epsilon}{\min}\:\epsilon\\
&\mathrm{s.t.}\qquad
\Big|||\mathbf{P}-\mathbf{P}_i||_2-d_i\Big|\leq\epsilon\:\: \text{for}\:\:i=1,2,3
\end{align}
where $\mathbf{P}$ and $\mathbf{P}_i$ are in $\mathbb{R}^3$ and $d_i$ is scalar for $i=1,2,3$.

I actually don't know how to convert these constraints into quadratic form or reformulate the problem in an appropriate way to use a solver. I really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming $d_i \ge \epsilon$, rewrite
$$|||\mathbf{P}-\mathbf{P}_i||_2-d_i|\leq\epsilon$$
as
$$d_i-\epsilon \le ||\mathbf{P}-\mathbf{P}_i||_2 \le d_i+\epsilon$$
and then square all three parts to obtain two quadratic inequality constraints.

Comment: Thank you so much. I was struggling with this for three hours

Comment: Glad to help.  Please mark my answer as accepted.